# nodejs sqlite server crash when existing param is written twice

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, routeparams

I've created a webapp that uses expressjs and sqlite3.
If for example I search for the name john in the table family:
http://mypage.com/search?name=john&table=family
It shows the results without any problem.
But if someones manually adds &table=xxxxxx after the previous link it automatically crashes.
I've been searching for a solution for a while now and couldn't come up with any.
How should I prevent this??

Comment: If someone adds &table=xxxxx manually the url looks like this: http://mypage.com/search?name=john&table=family&table=xxxxx 
So you are passing in two table values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code assumes table query param as string.

But if you put "&table=xxx" again in query string, query param for "table" become array.

/search?name=john&table=family&table=xxx

query = {"name":"john","table":["family","xxx"]}

Comment: yes, the table property gets converted into an array. To prevent the crash I came up with this ->     if (typeof table !== "string") { table = table[table.length-1]; } just to take into account the last value. Thanks